# How to retrieve visible text signature from a PDF?

Tags: itext

I am trying to retrieve signature informations from a PDF file, i was able to get all signed fields names using itext library :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream, null);
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
```

But what i really want is the exact visual text shown in the PDF doc, for instance for this document i want to get the text : **Rev.1:Signed by My Test Company**

[image: Signed PDF document]

Comment: *"the exact visual text shown in the PDF doc"* - but your screen shot does not focus on anything shown *in the PDF doc* but instead on something shown *outside the PDF doc*, in a dedicated region of a specific pdf viewer.  This is only loosely related to what is down in the Pdf doc.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the text is from the Adobe Reader. However in general it is possible. Within the java version the code would look like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream, null);
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();

for (String signatureName : names) {
    int revision = reader.getAcroFields().getRevision(signatureName);

    AcroFields.Item item = acroFields.getFieldItem(signatureName);
    PdfDictionary d = item.getMerged(0);
    PdfDictionary v = d.getAsDict(PdfName.V);

    if (v != null) {
        PdfString name = v.getAsString(PdfName.NAME);
        System.out.println("Rev."+revision+": Signed by "+ name.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @WarMachine Depending on the language settings of your Adobe Reader the exact static strings vary. If your program is for wide use, you will have to localize those strings.